# Setting Log4j JDBC props dynamically

Tags: log4j

My application needs to write to a DB. I would like to read the JDBC config values (url, password etc) from a config.xml file and set them to the log4.xml from within my code.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Have a logger for db logging:**


   `< logger name="jdbcLogger">`

   < level value="debug" />

   < /logger >
2. **Added JDBC appender from the code:**

`org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender dbAppender = new org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender();
        dbAppender.setDriver("mysql.driver.class.here");
        //set other properties
        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.setConversionPattern("insert ...");
        dbAppender.setLayout(patternLayout);
        dbLogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("jdbcLogger");
        dbLogger.addAppender(dbAppender);`